# $f(x)$ as a difference of two increasing functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function. Find $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ - two increasing functions, which difference equals $f(x)$, e.g. $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$.

Examples: 
$\arctan(x^3-9x)$ 
$\frac{1}{1+(\sin x)^2}$ 
the polynomial $x^5+px^2+qx+r$ when $p,q,r$ are constant 
$e^{x^3-9x}$

What I know is that if $f(x)$  is decreasing  you can make this: $f(x)=g(x)-h(x)$ when $g(x)=a$ and $h(x)=a-f(x)$, $a$=constant, but I can't see  how this can be used for these functions.

Comment: looks like you'll need to use the $\min,\max$ functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint. If $f(x)$ is increasing in an interval, give all that increase to $g(x)$ and keep $h(x)$ constant. If $f(x)$ is decreasing in an interval, give all that as an increase to $h(x)$ and keep $g(x)$ constant.

Your added work is to show that this will work for all *continuous* functions. You also need to clearly set the constant for when $g$ or $h$ is constant.